# Change Date format in SharePoint modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I want to change the format of date from DD/MM/YYYY to DD MMM YYYY in a Modern list. Is there any way to achieve this with column formatting?, we don't want to use calculated column.

Comment: So it is just for one specific list, not the entire site ?

Comment: Yes it's only for a specific list.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not currently possible to apply custom string formats with column formatting:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/issues/50

As you can see on [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), the operators to format dates are:

```
toLocaleString()
toLocaleDateString()
toLocaleTimeString()
```

You can use a calculated column, but if you don't want to use it you can do that with [SPFx Field Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer).

Answer (score 0):

Except calculated column, there is no OOB method that I could thought to achieve your purpose.

Maybe you can do this using code. For using code in modern experience list, as RiccardoGDev mentioned, you should use SPFx.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/enterprise-guidance